# Installed package was successful outside virtual env but errors inside virtual env

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv, pypi

I have a package "fretboardgtr" successfully installed outside virtual env using pip. The modules work without any errors.

I started a django project inside a virtual env and tried to install the same package inside the virtual env but it errors with the following error:

> Collecting fretboardgtr   Using cached
> fretboardgtr-0.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (32 kB) Processing
> /Users/sajwaltamrakar/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/83/85/db/f83adc7591329e230cb5bda2a339e66a8dbd0f69ade492db56/svglib-1.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
> Collecting Pillow>=7.1.2   Using cached Pillow-9.2.0.tar.gz (50.0 MB)
> Collecting webencodings>=0.5.1   Using cached
> webencodings-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB) Collecting
> svgwrite>=1.4   Using cached svgwrite-1.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
> Collecting cssselect2>=0.3.0   Using cached
> cssselect2-0.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB) Collecting lxml>=4.5.1
> Using cached lxml-4.9.1.tar.gz (3.4 MB) Collecting tinycss2>=1.0.2
> Using cached tinycss2-1.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB) Collecting
> reportlab>=3.5.42   Using cached reportlab-3.6.11.tar.gz (4.5 MB)
>
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>
> > ```
> >  command: /Users/MYNAME/Documents/Python/content_creator/CC_env/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/h2/xy8....
> > Complete output (10 lines):
> > ##### setup-python-3.9.1-macosx-11-x86_64: ================================================
> > ##### setup-python-3.9.1-macosx-11-x86_64: Attempting build of _rl_accel
> > ##### setup-python-3.9.1-macosx-11-x86_64: extensions from 'src/rl_addons/rl_accel'
> > ##### setup-python-3.9.1-macosx-11-x86_64: ================================================
> > ##### setup-python-3.9.1-macosx-11-x86_64: ===================================================
> > ##### setup-python-3.9.1-macosx-11-x86_64: Attempting build of _renderPM
> > ##### setup-python-3.9.1-macosx-11-x86_64: extensions from 'src/rl_addons/renderPM'
> > ##### setup-python-3.9.1-macosx-11-x86_64: ===================================================
> > ##### setup-python-3.9.1-macosx-11-x86_64: will use package libart 2.3.21
> > !!!!! cannot find ft2build.h
> > ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
> > ```

Comment: how you installed that inside env

Comment: What are thw versions of python inside and outside venv

Answer (score 0):

```
 sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
```

Probably your are missing this dependency